# Authenticating with Azure Active Directory on powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am attempting to explore the features of the [Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/2.0.0.98)

I have an Azure Account, and I have set up an Active Directory with multiple users.

My first goal is simple: show me the list of users.

So I type:

```
Connect-AzureAD
```

I am presented with a dialog and type in my user account and password. It returns on object of type `Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.PSAzureContext`.

I then type

```
Get-AzureADUser
```

And the error is:

> Get-AzureADUser : Error occurred while executing GetUsers
>
> Code: Authentication_Unauthorized
>
> Message: User was not found
>
> HttpStatusCode: Forbidden

I am still able to list the users using the Azure RM Powershell module. The following code works:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmADUser
```

---

What do I do to get `Get-AzureADUser` to work?

Comment: Nothing special. I suggest raising a support ticket with details from the most recent logs from %localappdata%\Microsoft\AzureAD\Powershell correlating to your attempt to list users. We in support look at the backend logs to see what lead to the error.

Comment: are you using ARM ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The cmdlet `Connect-AzureAD` establishes connection to ADD domian, after we login successed a confirmation will display:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> connect-azuread

Account                                Environment Tenant
-------                                ----------- ------
jasontest1@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com AzureCloud  xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The connection can be vaildated with this cmdlet `Get-AzureADDomain`, if the user is connected to AAD domain, where he has management **privileges** - the information about the domain will be displayed:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> get-azureaddomain

Name                                        AvailabilityStatus AuthenticationType
----                                        ------------------ ------------------
hcl.com                                                        Managed
msgamestudios.com                                              Managed
foobar.local                                                   Managed
multimap.com                                                   Managed
skypestaytogether.com                                          Managed
insightsquarterly.com.au                                       Managed
calanit.onmicrosoft.com                                        Federated
msft.ccsctp.net                                                Managed
ruffiangames.com                                               Managed
xn--m1bg0b0byewac1j8b.com                                      Managed
VoicesforInnovation.org                                        Managed
shaanximic.com                                                 Managed
www.yunnanmic.com                                              Managed
wsmbela.pss.com                                                Managed
fornax.off                                                     Managed
api.staging.yammer.com                                         Managed
codenauts.net                                                  Managed
acompli.com                                                    Managed
testdomains.co                                                 Managed
microsoft.hr                                                   Managed
Bayportali.mmdservice.com                                      Managed
contoso.com                                                    Managed
api.swrepository.com                                           Managed
Equivio.com                                                    Managed
sunshine.am                                                    Managed
microsoftaffiliates.com                                        Managed
```

If user has **no** admin privileges, we will get the error same as you.

```
Get-AzureADDomain : Error occurred while executing GetDomains
Code: Authentication_Unauthorized
Message: User was not found
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
```

The reason is that, **the cmdlet GetAzureADDomian has no tenant specified, so the connection was established to a domian, where user has no admin privileges.**

To ensure connection to expected AAD domian, the **tenant ID** must specified in call to `Connect-AzureAD` cmdlet.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Connect-AzureAD -TenantId
```

Comment: Solid gold! It would be so nice if Microsoft made actual documentation these days, instead of a bunch of "QuickStart" one page tutorials.

Comment: you made my day.. :)

Answer (score 9):

As already answered here, please use:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Connect-AzureAD -TenantId {YOUR_TENANT_ID}
Example:
PS C:\windows\system32> Connect-AzureAD -TenantId ce1af0ab-ae35-4f60-8f2d-944444444444
```

It's a common mistake to use TenantId we get when executing `Connect-AzureAd`, like following:

[image]

But use the `TenantId` from `Azure Portal --> Azure Active Directory --> Properties --> Directory Id`.

The `Directory Id` = `TenantId`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer from 2020+.  Thanks! +1