# Deleting Azure Directory failed. I should remove App-Registrations, but there are any more remaining

Tags: azure, powershell

i found this [article](https://stackoverrun.com/de/q/13138069)

but using the PS is not possible for me:
I am not able to connect to azure this way with my user (the powershell-login with .de-domain does not work) - Thank u MS!
Now i have no idea anymore, how to remove the directory.

Can you help me, please?

Greetings,
Ulrich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 2: Deleting the tenant**

[Authenticating with Azure Active Directory on powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301218/authenticating-with-azure-active-directory-on-powershell)

[AzureAD-Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0)

a)     `connect-AzureAD -tenantid <your-tenant-id>`
        Azure Active Directory --> Properties --> Directory ID

b)   `Get-AzureADApplication` --> (+)

For every Application:

`Remove-AzureADApplication -objectid <your-application-id>`
        --> (+)

then:

`Remove-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId <your-enterprise-application-id>`

Azure Active Directory --> Delete Directory --> Exterprise Applications

For every Exterprise Applications:
Click on row --> copy Object ID = `<your-enterprise-application-id>`

c) In my case i was able to delete the directories (tenants) after a) and b)

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Connecting to Azure via Powershell**

MSOnline seems to be [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0):

Now i installed [Install-Module AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0)

The login works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to the Germany cloud?  If so you need to specify the `-AzueEnvironment AzureGermanyCloud`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/connect-msolservice?view=azureadps-1.0

Comment: Hello Ken, it seems to be a problem with login-formula: i typed "yyy@xxx.de", but the error-message is: "xxx.de" befindet sich nicht in unserem System. Stellen Sie sicher, dass Sie Ihre E-Mail-Adresse richtig eingegeben haben. Das Format lautet üblicherweise "jemand@example.com" oder "jemand@example.onmicrosoft.com". Thank you for the link. I tried, but it is the same problem...

Comment: I also tried this script: 
$User = "yyy@xxx.de" 
$Password = "***" 
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$msolcred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($User,$SecurePassword) 
connect-msolservice -credential $msolcred -AzureEnvironment AzureGermanyCloud
Result is the same: No success...
connect-msolservice : Authentication Error: Bad username or password.
In Zeile:5 Zeichen:1

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17134  590

Comment: The first message is saying the yyy@xxx.de is not found in the system.  Are you a Global Admin for the AAD?  Do you know the AAD tenant name?  That would allow you to try the "jemand@example.onmicrosoft.com" username and possibly reset the password (if you set up an email or SMS phone number).

Comment: Hello Ken, thanks for your answer :-) Yes, i am the global admin. There is a misunderstanding: i typed "yyy@xxx.de" but the login-error-message was (translation) "xxx.de is not in our system...". so perhaps the prefix and the "@" is not recognized by the login-form-field... The pw is copy&paste from a passwordsafe, and i tried about 10-15 times, so i think, it can be excluded as an error-source... Also the credentials are fine for login in the Azure-Portal-Website.

Comment: Can you try to use Fiddler to see if it's trying to log on to `https://login.microsoftonline.de` or `https://login.microsoftonline.com`?

Comment: POST https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/GetCredentialType?mkt=de-DE HTTP/1.1

Response:{"Username":"xxx@yyy.de","Display":"xxxx@yyy.de","IfExistsResult":1,"ThrottleStatus":1,"Credentials":{"PrefCredential":1,"HasPassword":true,"RemoteNgcParams":null,"FidoParams":null,"SasParams":null},"EstsProperties":{"DomainType":1},"

Comment: Good idea, Ken: The Portal-Website-Login uses "login.microsoftonline.com" so i tried in Powershell:  connect-msolservice -AzureEnvironment AzureCloud. Now it uses "login.microsoft.com" too, but the error still remains

Comment: Is MFA enabled?  If so, take a look at https://supertekboy.com/2018/11/07/connect-msolservice-may-fail-when-mfa-is-enabled/

Comment: I followed the instructions:PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> find-module -name MSOnline

Version    Name                                Repository           Description
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------
1.1.183.17 MSOnline                            PSGallery            Microsoft Azure Active Directory Module for Wind... 
--> No Scuccess

Comment: PS-Error:
connect-msolservice : Authentication Error: Unexpected authentication failure.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ connect-msolservice -AzureEnvironment AzureCloud
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService

Comment: If you have support, you will want to open a ticket.  I suspect since you are here, you do not.  Hopefully someone from else can chime in.

Comment: Hello Ken, i think, i have solved the problem. Thank you very much for your help! Now i will post some links i found that are very helpful, then i will close this task. Greetings, Ulrich