# How to get New-AzureADPolicy to work in azure cloud shell

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cloud-services, azure-cloud-shell

I was able to run

```
Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview
```

But when I run

```
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy" {"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"02:00:00"}}')
```

It run into this error

```
New-AzureADPolicy: The term 'New-AzureADPolicy' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

How do I get this keyword to work in cloud shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

```
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy" {"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"02:00:00"}}') -DisplayName TestPolicy -IsTenantDefault
```

[image]

Please note that, before installing **`AzureADPreview`** you need uninstall **`AzureAD`** Module like below:

```
Uninstall-Module AzureAD 
Install-Module AzureADPreview 
Import-Module AzureADPreview 
Get-Module -Name AzureADPreview
connect-AzureAd
```

[image]

***I tried to create the policy by using the below command and got the results successfully like below:***

```
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"02:00:00"}}') -DisplayName "WebPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Set lifetimes for tokens - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes#create-a-policy-for-web-sign-in)

Comment: I got was able to get to step `connect-AzureAd` but after that `New-AzureADPolicy` failed with following error```New-AzureADPolicy : Error occurred while executing NewPolicy
Code: Authentication_Unauthorized
Message: User was not found.
InnerError:```

Comment: Please check this [Authenticating with Azure Active Directory on powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301218/authenticating-with-azure-active-directory-on-powershell)