# Set-AzureADUser : Error occurred while executing SetUser Code: Authentication_Unauthorized

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and getting below error:
The users exists, How to fix this issue? Thanks.

> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-AzureADUser  -ObjectId
> TestUser1@home1.onmicrosoft.com -
> AccountEnabled $false

```
Set-AzureADUser : Error occurred while executing SetUser
Code: Authentication_Unauthorized
Message: User was not found.
RequestId: b32c6fe2-d785-4d30-acc1-67ffba685269
DateTimeStamp: Sat, 20 Aug 2022 16:45:06 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureADUser  -ObjectId TestUser1@home1.onmicrosoft.com -Account ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AzureADUser], ApiException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.SetUser
```

> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authenticating with Azure Active Directory on powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301218/authenticating-with-azure-active-directory-on-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error when I tried to connect with wrong `Tenant-ID`:***

```
 Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId UPN -AccountEnabled $false
```

[image]

**The error usually occurs**, if you are connecting Azure AD with **Insufficient privileges** (*user has no admin privileges*) or connecting with the wrong **`Tenant-ID`** .

***To resolve the error, try connecting Azure AD by using below commands:***

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId **** 
Get-AzureADDomain
```

[image]

Make sure the **AuthenticationType** is **`Managed`** while running `Get-AzureADDomain` command.

After connecting Azure AD with the required **privileges** and correct **`Tenant-ID`** , I am able to set the user successfully like below:

```
 Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId UPN -AccountEnabled $false
```

[image]

***To confirm the above, you can also check in the Portal:***

[image]

**UPDATE:**

**To disable bulk Azure AD users, please try the below:**

**CSV file:**
[image]

```
$CSVrecords = Import-Csv "C:\Users\file.csv"
foreach ($CSVrecord in $CSVrecords) {
$ObjectID = $CSVrecord.ObjectID
$user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID "$ObjectID"
if ($user) {
try{
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $ObjectID -AccountEnabled $false
} catch {
$FailedUsers += $ObjectID
Write-Warning "$ObjectID user found, but FAILED to update."
}
}
else {
$SkippedUsers += $ObjectID
Write-Warning "$ObjectID not found, skipped"
}
}
```

***I am able to disable the users successfully like below:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. However, when I'm trying to read UPN from my CSV file like this:   Import-Csv "C:\Users\Myfile.csv" | ForEach { Set-AzureADUser -ObjectID UPN -AccountEnabled $false}     It gives me error:  Set-AzureADUser : Error occured while executing SetUser code: Request_ResourceNotFound Message: Resource UPN does not exists or one of its queried reference property objects are not present. However, I'm able to execute it individually fine. Any idea, how to load the UPN from CSV file and do a bulk disable ? Thanks

Comment: Please check the updated answer.